# How to hide the admin notices of my wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm developing a WordPress plugin and on the settings page I generate a form where it´s validated on another function.

On this validator function I stack the error calling the add_settings_error

The problems is that I want to stack this error but I don´t want to show these messages.

Does a way exist to hide this message?

Thank you!

Comment: in ur wp-config.php File if define('WP_DEBUG', true);
than try this define('WP_DEBUG', false);

Comment: I have setted this var in false and don't works. Thanks anyway